Universal property of tensor products
I have a rather stupid question about the university property of tensor products.
Assume that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are $k$-vector spaces. From the universal property or adjointness, we have $\text{Hom}_{k\text{-bilinear}}(V_1\times V_2,V_1\times V_2)\cong \text{Hom}_\text{k-linear}(V_1\bigotimes_k V_2, V_1\times V_2)$, so there is  $V_1\times V_2\overset{\iota}{\to} V_1\bigotimes V_2\to V_1\times V_2$, whose composition is the identity. This implies that $\iota$ is injective. (Is it true up to here?)
Then why cannot we use such an argument to show that if the $k$-basis of $V_1$, $V_2$ are $\{a_i\}$, $\{b_j\}$ respectively, then the $k$-basis of $V_1\otimes V_2$ is $\{a_i\otimes b_j\}$? Since $\sum\lambda_{i,j}(a_i,b_j)$ is never $0$ when $\lambda_{i,j}$ are not all zero, we have the $k$-linear independence of $\{a_i\otimes b_j\}$.
I searched this question in the stackexchange, but did not find such an argument. I am aware of the existing proof using the universal property, but I am asking about the correctness of this specific argument.
Also, note that if this argument works, not only does it uses the universal property, but it constructs explicitly an isomorphism $V_1\times V_2\cong V_1\bigotimes_k V_2$. This isomorphism already follows from the injectivity and an additional assumption that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces. But the case of infinite-dimension also follows, because then $V_1$ and $V_2$ can be viwed as a colimit of finite-dimensional vector spaces, but tensor product is left-adjoint, so it already commutes with the tensor product.

@Student I am aware of this post. But I am asking about the proof using the argument described in the second paragraph.

@Student updated

I voted to reopen the question because the linked answer does not explain where the OP's argument fails.

Your argument is not correct. The identity on $V_1 \times V_2$ is not bilinear and thus does not factorize through $\iota$.
